# jQuery functions return undefined

Tags: jquery, function

I normally code in a different style, a more basic style. So I'm trying a new way of doing things but i can't seem to get it.

My `console.log` returns a jQuery object: **console.log(accountMenu.child);**

But this returns undefined: **console.log(accountMenu.child.css('top'));**. And other jQuery methods are the same. what am i doing wrong?

```
var accountMenu = {
accountButton: jQuery('.my-account-btn'),
child: jQuery('#my-account-droplist'),
container: jQuery('.my-account-droplist-container'),

closeAccount: function() { 
    accountButton.removeClass('expanded');
    child.animate({
        "top": child.outerHeight() * -1
    }, 650);
},

openAccount: function(){
    accountButton.addClass('expanded');
    child.animate({
        "top": 0
    }, 650);
    this.setTimeout(function(){closeAccount()}, 6000);
}};

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

accountMenu.child.css({"top": accountMenu.child.outerHeight() * -1});

console.log(accountMenu.child);

//animate account drop down
accountMenu.accountButton.click(function() {
    //check if open or closed
    if ( accountMenu.accountButton.hasClass('expanded') ){
        accountMenu.accountMenu.closeAccount();
    } else{
        //first close mycart
        if ( jQuery('.top-cart > div').hasClass('expanded') ){
            Enterprise.TopCart.hideCart();
            setTimeout(function(){
                accountMenu.accountMenu.openAccount();
            }, 700);
        }else {
            accountMenu.accountMenu.openAccount();
        };
    };
});
});
```

Comment: Is jQuery properly loaded? When does `.css("top")` give undefined - before or after your `document.ready` fires?

Comment: I get this output  from the **console.log(accountMenu.child);**: 
[context: document, selector: "#my-account-droplist", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function…]

And this output from **console.log(accountMenu.child.css('top'));**:
[div#my-account-droplist, context: document, selector: "#my-account-droplist", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function…]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're aware of `jQuery(document).ready()` and you already use it. However, you fetch data from the page outside that block, before the page has finished loading.

**Edit:** If you're asking how to make `accountMenu` global, you have to declare it with the `var` keyword in the appropriate scope:

```
var accountMenu;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    accountMenu = {
        accountButton: jQuery('.my-account-btn'),
        ...
    };
});
```

Comment: aah okay that makes sense. But i need to access the data from else where thats why I put it outside the ready() function. what would be a better way to format this?

Answer (score 0):

> *"My console.log returns a jQuery object: `console.log(accountMenu.child);`"*

That's because `$("any selector")` always returns a jQuery object, but if no elements match the jQuery object will be empty and then `.css()` will return `undefined`.

Any JS code that tried to access/manipulate DOM elements needs to run after the elements in question have been parsed by the browser, which means you should either move the `var accountMenu = { ...` declaration into your document ready handler or move the script element to the end of the body (just before the `</body>` tag - in which case you wouldn't need the ready handler at all).

Comment: okay, but then how would i call the two functions from outside of the jQuery(document).ready() function?

Comment: I don't understand. Why wouldn't you call them the same way you're already calling them?

Comment: From where? Don't you always want to access your data from some trigger (whether it be `document.ready` or some button click, etc)?

Comment: Because theres another .js file which uses prototype - from there i need to call the **openAccount** and **closeAccount** functions.

Comment: JS code not contained in a function will run automatically, so if the script is located at the end of the body it will just run after all the elements have been parsed. If there is a separate script in another JS file just include it at the end of the body too, _after_ the script that defines the objects it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong in getting variable accountMenu in side Document.ready.I think you need to do like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var accountMenu = {
accountButton: jQuery('.my-account-btn'),
child: jQuery('#my-account-droplist'),
container: jQuery('.my-account-droplist-container'),

closeAccount: function() { 
    accountButton.removeClass('expanded');
    child.animate({
        "top": child.outerHeight() * -1
    }, 650);
},

openAccount: function(){
    accountButton.addClass('expanded');
    child.animate({
        "top": 0
    }, 650);
    this.setTimeout(function(){closeAccount()}, 6000);
}};

accountMenu.child.css({"top": accountMenu.child.outerHeight() * -1});

console.log(accountMenu.child);

//animate account drop down
accountMenu.accountButton.click(function() {
    //check if open or closed
    if ( accountMenu.accountButton.hasClass('expanded') ){
        accountMenu.accountMenu.closeAccount();
    } else{
        //first close mycart
        if ( jQuery('.top-cart > div').hasClass('expanded') ){
            Enterprise.TopCart.hideCart();
            setTimeout(function(){
                accountMenu.accountMenu.openAccount();
            }, 700);
        }else {
            accountMenu.accountMenu.openAccount();
        };
    };
});
});
```